# What is faster way FindBitmap ot Lockbits c# find the same images

Tags: c#, image, compare

Which metod gonna find me picture in another picutre? Findmap or Lockbits?

Lockbits code:

```
bool equals = true;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);
            BitmapData bmpData1 = bmp1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp1.PixelFormat);
            BitmapData bmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);
            unsafe
            {
                byte* ptr1 = (byte*)bmpData1.Scan0.ToPointer();
                byte* ptr2 = (byte*)bmpData2.Scan0.ToPointer();
                int width = rect.Width * 3; // for 24bpp pixel data
                for (int y = 0; equals && y < rect.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        if (*ptr1 != *ptr2)
                        {
                            equals = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        ptr1++;
                        ptr2++;
                    }
                    ptr1 += bmpData1.Stride - width;
                    ptr2 += bmpData2.Stride - width;
                }
            }
            bmp1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);
            bmp2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);
```

And there is code of Findbotmap :

```
 private bool FindBitmap(Bitmap bmpNeedle, Bitmap bmpHaystack, out Point location)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int outerX = 0; outerX < bmpHaystack.Width - bmpNeedle.Width; outerX++)
                {
                    for (int outerY = 0; outerY < bmpHaystack.Height - bmpNeedle.Height; outerY++)
                    {
                        for (int innerX = 0; innerX < bmpNeedle.Width; innerX++)
                        {
                            for (int innerY = 0; innerY < bmpNeedle.Height; innerY++)
                            {
                                Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
                                Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);

                                if (cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B)
                                {
                                    goto notFound;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        location = new Point(outerX - 8, outerY - 32);
                        return true;
                        notFound:
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                location = Point.Empty;
                return false;
            }
            catch { location = Point.Empty; return false; }
        }
```

The question is what method is faster and why?
I searched a lot of topic etc. and still can't find what method gonna be better to check image inside another image  ( or 2 images are the same ).
Can anyone who knows topic tell more about it? And what method should i use to check if images are the same?
Thanks for tips and please don't make duplicates.. i searched a lot and can't  find respond for this topic.

Comment: GetPixel will always be very slow. The loop logic is a different matter and can be used on both lockbits and getpixel methods. Does any method actually work correctly? If so, why do you have to ask us about speed??

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/